# tabindex skips a clickable element even though it is included in tabindex order

Tags: angularjs, tabindex

I am using Angular JS in my application. I am using tabindex on certain clickable elements to support keyboard users for the application.

My understanding about tabindex is that suppose an element A gets tabindex = 1, element B gets tabindex = 3, element C with tabindex = 2, then the order of tabbing will be A -> C -> B

I have provided the following code snippet:

```
<div class="aaa">
    <a class="bbb" data-ng-click="cancel()" tabindex="7">{{"cancel" | translate}}
    </a>
    <a class="ccc" data-ng-disabled="abcForm.$pristine || abcForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="abcForm.$pristine || abcForm.$invalid || function()" tabindex="6">{{"save" | translate}}
    </a>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<form name="abcForm">
    <div tabindex ="1">a form</div>
    <input tabindex="2" type="text" data-ng-model="xyz1" data-ng-required="true" data-ng-pattern="//" data-ng-trim="true" ng-maxlength="10">
    <input tabindex="3" type="text" data-ng-model="xyz2" data-ng-required="true" data-ng-pattern="//" data-ng-trim="true" ng-maxlength="10">
    <input tabindex="4" type="text" data-ng-model="xyz3" data-ng-required="true" data-ng-pattern="//" data-ng-trim="true" ng-maxlength="10">
    <input tabindex="5" type="text" data-ng-model="xyz4" data-ng-required="true" data-ng-pattern="//" data-ng-trim="true" ng-maxlength="10">
</form>
```

from tabindex 1 to 5, tabs will be ordered perfectly, my expectation is that save button with tabindex=6 will appear before cancel button tabindex=7 but the problem is save button gets ignored completely

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: elements those are disabled for user interaction are not added into tabbing, check if ur save button is disabled